# Differences between Foundation frameworks on Mac OS X and iPhone

Tags: iphone, frameworks, macos, wrapper, foundation

Curious:

Why is it that Foundation on OS X contains a wrapper for CFHost (NSHost) but not CFSocket, and Foundation on iPhone OS doesn't even have NSHost?

And as an aside, are there any libraries or has any written any wrappers for CFHost and CFSocket on the iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly enough, the iPhone version of Foundation does actually include the `NSHost` class, but Apple doesn't provide [the headers for it](http://ericasadun.com/iPhoneDocs300/_n_s_host_8h-source.html).

Comment: It's likely private, and likely to change betweet releases.

Comment: It is private, but hasn't changed since 1.0; still, using the CFHost functions isn't too difficult and is recommended over the Foundation equivalent